# How to make it such that there are two seperate groups of cells in the same tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

How do I make it such that when names2 is not equals to names, it will add the missing strings from names into the table view but with a different text style?

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var names = [String]()
    var identities = [String]()
    var names2 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        names = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
        identities = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        names2 = ["First", "Second"]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

        cell?.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]



        return cell!
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let vc = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vc)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**For images in collection view**

```
import UIKit

class MedalViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var imagesArray = [String]()
    var identities = [String]()
    var identities2 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        imagesArray = ["1", "2", "3"]
        identities = ["Shield", "Tie", "Star"]
        identities2 = ["Shield", "Tie"]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imagesArray[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagesArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let vc = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(vc)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
        viewController?.title = self.identities[indexPath.row]
    }

}
```

How do I make it such that the missing identifier in this case "Star" in which its image is "3" is greyed out in the `collectionsView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that `names2` is contains `names` array object inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and then change the text style you want.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    cell?.textLabel!.text = names[indexPath.row]
    if (names2.contains(names[indexPath.row])) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor() //Set other style that you want
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor() //Set other style that you want
    }
    return cell!
}
```

**Edit:** I doesn't get properly about image but you could try some thing like this.

```
if (identities2.contains(identities[indexPath.row])) {
    cell.imageView = UIImage(named: identities[indexPath.row]) 
}
else {
    cell.imageView = UIImage(named: "DefaultGrayImage") //Set default image not in identities2
}
```

Comment: I for got to put one `)` bracket, check edited answer.

Comment: Now how do we do it with images? Lets say the image is not part of the array how do we add those missing images (but greyed out)?

Comment: Which image you are taking about?

Comment: It's for a different but similar code. Let's say identities and identities2 are not equal, how do we make it such that the missing identity, in which case it's image is "Star" get's a grey image in the collection view? I just edited the question above